# Modifying array/structure globally doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, global-variables

I think I am near the mark of understanding the concept of pointers, but I am having an issue I can't solve on my own...
I am trying to modify a structure by a function:

```
struct structure
{
    double lower[2];
};

void function(struct structure *structure1)
{
    structure1->lower[0] = 1;
    structure1->lower[1] = 2;
}

int main()
{
    double a[2] = {0, 0};

    struct structure structure1 = { {a[0], a[1]} };

    function(&structure1);
    printf("%f, %f\n", a[0], a[1]);
```

When I try to print `a` now,
the values remain the same — it prints `0, 0`.
Why didn't the array change globally?

Comment: Why do you think it should? C does not work like a spreadsheet.

Comment: Are you setting the `double` values to `integers`? Try using 1.0, 2.0, and 0.0 where you're setting the values.

Comment: When i print inside of the function it shows the values i want it to have. This cant be the issue...

Answer (score 3):

> the values remain the same — it prints `0, 0`. Why didn't the array change globally?

- Your array `a` is not a global variable (it's local in `main`)
- You never really changed anything in `a` - you merely used its elements to initialize `structure1`
- Your `function` changes `structure1` - but it has nothing to do with array `a`

Comment: You need to decide which one to modify? array? struct? You don't need global var to just modify an array.

Answer (score 0):

Using this one, you are calling a local variable which gives the value 0,0:

```
printf("%f, %f\n", a[0], a[1]);
```

Try this

```
printf("%f, %f\n", structure1->lower[0], structure1->lower[1]);
```

to call globally.